# EF Core: Lazy-loaded navigations must have backing fields

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I understand, what is a backing field and work with it ten years. But really I don't see what is the mistake in the code below:

```
public class Cal
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public double? AreaSqFt { get; set; }
    public int? NumberOfPeople { get; set; }

    private ICollection<CalcOfSpaceContaminant> _сalcOfSpaceContaminants;
    public virtual ICollection<CalcOfSpaceContaminant> CalcOfSpaceContaminants { get => _сalcOfSpaceContaminants ??= new List<CalcOfSpaceContaminant>(); protected set => _сalcOfSpaceContaminants = value; }

}

public class CalcOfSpaceContaminant
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public double? Vr { get; set; }
    public double? Cbz { get; set; }
    public double? Fr { get; set; }

    public int CalcID { get; set; }
    public virtual Cal Cal { get; set; }
}
```

and mapping:

```
public class CalcOfSpaceContaminantMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<CalcOfSpaceContaminant>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<CalcOfSpaceContaminant> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable(nameof(CalcOfSpaceContaminant));
        builder.HasKey(p => p.ID);

        builder.HasOne(contaminant => contaminant.Cal)
            .WithMany(cal => cal.CalcOfSpaceContaminants)
            .HasForeignKey(k => k.CalcID)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }
}
```

and then

```
        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new CalcOfSpaceContaminantMap());
```

But when I try to create a migration, I receive:

> No backing field was found for property 'Cal.CalcOfSpaceContaminants'.
> Lazy-loaded navigations must have backing fields. Either name the
> backing field so that it is discovered by convention or configure the
> backing field to use.

What is wrong here?
Thanks

**ADDED #1**

It's not depended on `ICollection` because I use `ICollection` everywhere, e.g.:

```
public partial class Zone
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ZoneName { get; set; }

    private ICollection<Cal> _cals;
    public virtual ICollection<Cal> Cals { get => _cals ??= new List<Cal>(); protected set => _cals = value; }
}

public class CalMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Cal>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Cal> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable(nameof(Cal));
        builder.HasKey(p => p.ID);

        builder.HasOne(p => p.Zone)
            .WithMany(z => z.Cals)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.ZoneId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }
}
```

**ADDED #2**

After @akseli post below I replaced cyrillic letter 'c' to latin and it works. I thought problem was in that letter, but I have the other place:

```
    //public virtual ICollection<DownloadCenterFile> DownloadCenterFiles { get; protected set; } = new List<DownloadCenterFile>();


    private ICollection<DownloadCenterFile> _files;
    public virtual ICollection<DownloadCenterFile> DownloadCenterFiles { get => _files ??= new List<DownloadCenterFile>(); protected set => _files = value; }
```

this code does not work (says similar, no backing field), but if I uncomment first line `public virtual ICollection<DownloadCenterFile> DownloadCenterFiles { get; protected set; } = new List<DownloadCenterFile>();` and comment these 2 - it works. I don't see any cyrillic letters here. Seems, the problem is in my approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reviewing your code, I realized something very strange. It seems that you have some kind of encoding issue where the `c` character is actually being interpreted differently.

Below, you can see a screenshot of a simple diff, one with the code copy-pasted from here, and the other where I typed out the variable name by hand.

As you can see, there is a difference with `c`.
[image: diff results of c backing field names]
Furthermore, copy pasting each of the `c` characters into a unicode character detector yields the following results:
[image: results of c character comparison]

This leads me to think that EF is unable to detect your naming conventions correctly because of the "weird" `c` character that changes from place to place.

You might want to rewrite all of the code to make sure that you're getting the actually correct unicode characters everywhere you're referencing `_calcOfSpaceContaminants`.

Comment: Yeah, it's the Cyrillic letter C. This is a common problem of Russian developers: English c and Russian с are located on the same keyboard button.

Comment: If he changes all instances of the cyrillic `c` everything should start working correctly. It must really be a pain to have to deal with issues like that on a daily basis.

Comment: @akseli you are genius! I spent much time and even could not imagine that problem is in it.  I'm Ukrainian, so, cyrillic letter 'c' and latin on the same button, probably, I typed anything on ukrainian something else, then switched to code, tried to type "blind method", then found it, cleared, but not 'c'....

Comment: @akseli but, in any case, seems, the problem is not only in this. I will add to main post

Comment: @OlegSh Have you tried changing `public int CalcID { get; set; }` to `public int CalID { get; set; }` which would following naming conventions?

Comment: @akseli no, it's not depended. I just refactored names...